# How to compute sheaf cohomology of a classifying space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, classifying-spaces, group-extensions

[David Wigner](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183532101) showed that the group cohomology invented by [Calvin Moore](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1997540?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) can be related to sheaf cohomology when the coefficient is discrete by constructing a locally constant sheaf on the classifying space of the group. In the case where the group action is trivial, the computation is simple since we reduce the sheaf cohomology to a simpler topological cohomology. However, when the group action is non-trivial, I am not sure how to perform computations. Perhaps, we can reduce the problem to Čech cohomology in some way. Maybe, there are some other techniques. Is there any reference from which I can learn how to do explicit computations?